# Error in assignment operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class Array
{
private:
    int *ptr;
    int size;
    
public:
    Array& operator = (const Array& rhs);
};

Array& Array::operator = (const Array& rhs)
{
    ptr = new int [rhs.size];
    size = rhs.size;
    
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        ptr[i] = rhs.ptr[i];
        
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Array a;
    Array b;    
        
    a = b;
}
```

What are problems with this code?

First thing I can observe is that `size`'s value have not been defined. So there will be an error.

`size` is private so I can't assign it a value from main, yet that is a parameter of assignment operator. Where do I assign the value?

I tried to assign the value of `rhs.size` inside the definition of the = operator but then it threw segmentation fault. Why?

I don't understand what are they intending to do with this for loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        ptr[i] = rhs.ptr[i];
```

I want to understand what is happening with this code.

Comment: Don't forget to clear out any existing allocations before reassigning `ptr`.

Comment: How do you create one of these in the first place? You need a regular constructor of some sort. Your default constructor doesn't really do anything.

Comment: _"I don't understand what are they intending to do with this for loop"_ It's a deep copy of the content of `rhs.ptr` array. There's another issue here, you have to clear pre-existing contents of `ptr`

Comment: Since `a.size`, `b.size`, `a.ptr`, and `b.ptr` are all uninitialised, accessing their values gives undefined behaviour.   The `operator=()` accesses and uses the values of `b.size` and `b.ptr`, so the behaviour is undefined.     A "segmentation fault" is one of the many possible symptoms of undefined behaviour.    What you need to do is provide a default constructor for `Array` (a constructor that can accept no parameters) that initialises the `ptr` and `size` members to some sensible defaults (e.g. `size` to a positive value, and `ptr` to be `new int[size]`).

Comment: Also, the assignment operator needs to somehow release the previous value of `ptr`.  Simply assigning to it will cause the previously allocated memory to be leaked.   Lastly, look up the "rule of three" or (C++11 and later) "rule of five" - if your class has to provide an assignment operator, it also needs a copy constructor and destructor to behave consistently.

Comment: You simply need some constructors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we can talk about the `operator=`, we need to realise that the class is fundamentally broken: it has no working constructor, and it is violating the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and is therefore not managing its resources properly.

*After* these two points have been fixed, (but really only *after* that!), we can turn to the implementation of `operator=`. Let’s first address your three points:

> First thing I can observe is that `size`'s value have not been defined. So there will be an error.

Once the class has a working constructor, `size` will have a defined value.

> `size` is private so I can't assign it a value from main, yet that is a parameter of assignment operator. Where do I assign the value?

In the constructor.

> I tried to assign the value of `rhs.size` inside the definition of the = operator but then it threw segmentation fault. Why?

*How* did you assign it? What value did you try to give it? Since `rhs` is `const&` (as it should be!), you *can’t* assign to its members — this will result in a compile-time error, not in a segmentation fault. In fact, the size of `rhs` is part of the *precondition* of the function. It must not be modified (hence the use of `const&`).

Here are some more things that are wrong with the function:

1. It does not guard against self-assignment (what if `this == &rhs`?).
2. It does not deallocate previously-allocated memory in `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

With no constructor there's no way to allocate memory in the first place to copy, no way to assign `size`, and so on. You need to add that capability to test your copy feature.

I've sketched in some more code here to get this more operational, though there's obviously still a lot of work to do:

```
#include <iostream>

class Array
{
private:
    int *ptr;
    int size;
    
public:
    // Simple default constructor
    Array(int size = 0) : ptr(new int[size]), size(size) {
    }

    int getSize() const { return size; };

    Array& operator=(const Array& rhs);
};

Array& Array::operator=(const Array& rhs)
{
    // Delete any previous allocation
    delete[] ptr;

    ptr = new int[rhs.size];
    size = rhs.size;
    
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        ptr[i] = rhs.ptr[i];
        
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Array a(5);
    Array b;

    std::cout << "a size=" << a.getSize() << std::endl;

    b = a;

    std::cout << "b size=" << b.getSize() << std::endl;
}
```

Keep in mind it's called `operator=` as one word, not `operator =` all spaced out. The syntax doesn't care, but programmers do as it parses visually in a whole different way.

Note that this is a long way from idiomatic C++, like using `size_t` is preferable for "size" type arguments, but there's a long, long list of things you'll need to pick up and learn as you go.

Comment: This code is only marginally better than OP’s (arguably it’s worse since it adds more bad code, e.g. the constructor using assignment rather than an initialiser), and I honestly think posting this is the *opposite* of helping OP. It’s more likely to mislead than to help them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'd prefer to use `std::vector` but that defeats the purpose here. Can you initialize `ptr` with `new` in an initializer list?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've fixed that and the `delete[]` call.